# C++ 2d Array byref passing

Tags: c++, arrays, excel

For several years, I have been creating and using an app that uses Excel/VBA front end that passes data to a c++ dll for acceleration. A frequent problem I encounter is that VBA uses column-major 2d arrays and and c++ uses row-major 2d arrays. I have no problems using pointers in C++ to access the passed VBA data (e.g., 2-dim double arrays). From VBA I pass byref which in C++ is a pointer to the 1st array double, and the height & width of the passed 2d array. Example c++ code demonstrating my problem is below. In the C++ code, I would like to be able in C++ to define typedef or equivalent 2d access arr[r][c] per the last line in below code. I would also like to define 1d access, e.g.,arr1[i*c+j].

I have done extensive web search, but have not found solutions that I can get to work. Guidance will be greatly appreciated.

```
// Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
// #include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
const int r = 5;
const int c = 6;
//typedef arr (*arrpt)[*][c];
int main() {
    double arr[c][r]={ 1 };
    double* arrpt = &arr[0][0];
    int i, j, num;
    num = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++ ) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            *(arrpt + i +j*r) = (double)num; // Create column major array, e.g., VBA
            num++;
        }
    }
    double arr1[r * c];
    double* arr1pt = &arr1[0];
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            *(arr1pt + i*c +j) = *(arrpt + i + j * r);
        }
    }
    // double arr1v[r][c] = (*arr1pt)[r][c]; // this does not work. How?
}
```

Comment: `// double arr1v[r][c] = (*arr1pt)[r][c]; // this does not work. How?` -- So how relevant is all of the code that is above that line?  Is your real goal simply to assign a 1-dimensional array to a 2d array?  For example: `double a[2][3]; double b[6];` and then somehow `a = b;`?

Comment: `arr1v`  is not defined.

Comment: All the code above double arr1v .... line works perfectly. the 2nd loop converts from column major array to row major array for data use in C++.  I am doing algorithm development work and accessing arrays as arriv[i][j] is much more efficient to develop and debug. Also, pointer declared arrays aren't viewable in VS2109 debugger, only in memory.  I thought double arriv[r][c] defines arriv? And I want it to access arr1 as 2d array without using pointers? I thought typedef, or perhaps using, can do this declaration? But so far can't do?

Comment: @JimGunn -- *Also, pointer declared arrays aren't viewable in VS2109 debugger* -- One rule is to not let a debugger decide how you write code.  Second, the Visual Studio debugger has various options to view pointer data as if it's an array, such as `ptr, 14`, instead of just `ptr` if, for example `ptr` is defined as `double *ptr;`, and you want to view 14 items starting at `ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

It´s difficult to understand what you are asking: Do you want to use a notation column-row in like arr[c][r] without copying ? or you just want to copy from a col-row array in a c-like [r][c] ?
Typedef creates just a type alias, it does not "compute" array indexes, I don´t think that this convertion col-row to row-col will happens without some computation.

May be you are asking for a slicing https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice.

Sample of col-row notation without copying: https://godbolt.org/z/sxrfh8arG

```
template<typename T, int colsN, int rowsN>
struct colRow {
  using value_type = T;
  value_type* data;

  struct col_ref {
    colRow& ref;
    int col;

          value_type& operator[](int row)       { return ref.data[col * rowsN + row]; }
    const value_type& operator[](int row) const { return ref.data[col * rowsN + row]; }
  };

        col_ref operator[](int col)       { return col_ref{*this, col}; }
  const col_ref operator[](int col) const { return col_ref{*this, col}; }
};

double x[] = { 10, 20, ... }; 
colRow<double, 4, 5> cr {x};
x[2][3] = 23;
```